# Slick slider - slick-carousel.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I wanted to test [slick-slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) on my page, since I had some problems with swiper slider. I have followed the instructions on their page, and included the cdn links for it, these are all my scripts:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.spid.se/sdk/spid-sdk-2.1.0-var.js"></script>
<script>$(document).foundation();</script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/issue-images.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/magazine-detail.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/slider.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/scroll-reset.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/alex-box.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/slick-carousel.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

I am initiating the slider in my slick-carousel.js script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slick-carousel').slick({
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });
});
```

But I get the above in the title mentioned error, why is that?
I have even downloaded a file from cdn: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js
and added it to my scripts before the script where I initiate it but I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you included the slick plugin file?

Comment: Isn't that it:  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script> ?

Comment: Yea right.. I missed that sorry.. do you see any other error in console?

Comment: (Unrelated, but probably shouldn't link directly to a github repo.) Have you verified that it's actually being loaded?

Comment: That link is giving me 404 file not found error.. How about you

Comment: I have also tried with this one, and got the same error: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js

Comment: How can I verify it is loaded? @DaveNewton

Comment: this is a jquery issue. try getting rid of `integrity` and `crossorigin` from your `<a>` and see if `$` returns a DOM element.

Comment: I did remove it, and it returns an element, but I still get the same error

Comment: @Leff Check your browser console's network tab and ensure the assets you are trying to load are actually loading.

Comment: they are all loading @DaveNewton

Comment: I managed to get it working after placing it below all scripts, I don't know what is the reason, I am a javascript beginner, but it works now